# Input form is judged to be empty even after value is set by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I'm trying to write a small script which automatically inputs a username in [this login page](https://secure.sakura.ad.jp/rs/cp/). According to Inspector (of Firefox), the input field is identified as the CSS selector `input.input.input-text.input-default`. So I wrote the script below.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    window.setTimeout(() => {
        const username = document.querySelector('input.input.input-text.input-default');
        username.setAttribute('value', 'test');
    }, 100); //waits a little until the input form becomes available

})();
```

This actually succeeds in inputting the username `test`, but when I input the password and click the submit button, the error message

> username is required

is printed even though the field is not empty.

After that, if I click the username field, append any character, remove the character and then again click the submit button (see gif below), now the value of the field is correctly interpreted and the error message

> Authentication failed

is printed, which is totally ok since we use the invalid `test` as a username.

[image]

I think this behavior comes from events associated with the input field. According to Inspector, `focus`, `invalid`, `keydown`, `mousedown` and `onChange` events are bound to the field. However, even if I execute

```
username.dispatchEvent(new Event('onChange'));
```

or such, the value is still interpreted as empty.

Two questions:

- How can I make the script work in this case?
- If you succeed in making the script work, could you tell me how you have analyzed the code structure of the website? Now I use Inspector but it seems insufficient.

Comment: Please provide HTML code of form also.

Comment: @ikiK You can just visit the website I linked in the first line of OP. I'm sorry I cannot paste the entire code here because it's complicated and it's not open-source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Question 1

Just adding the line below to the first snippet, the problem has been solved.

```
username.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));
```

So the resultant code should be

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    window.setTimeout(() => {
        const username = document.querySelector('input.input.input-text.input-default');
        username.setAttribute('value', 'test');
        username.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true})); //only difference
    }, 100);

})();
```

I do **not** know, however, why `{bubbles: true}` does the trick.

#### Question 2

Here is how I came up with the line:

1. When I execute `console.log(username)`, I found the object has the property `__reactEventHandlers` who has `onChange` method. Since

```
username.dispatchEvent(new Event('onChange'));
```

```
username.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```
username.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

, etc. didn't work at all, I suspected the `__reactEventHandlers` is relevant in this case.

2. To call the `onChange` method from JavaScript, I googled "javascript call react onchange" and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31056122/8776746).

---

Again, I do **not** know why `{bubbles: true}` does the trick, which should be appended to this answer or be explained in another answer.

Comment: Is this a React application? You definitely do NOT want to change values using DOM manipulation. No (sane) one will spend the time to figure out how your React components look like using the dev tools, if you can't post the source code then write a minimal example to reproduce your issue (hint...you have to set the value using what React offers, not setting `value` attribute).

Comment: It might be the `setXyz()` function if you're using `useState()`, or `setState()` for a class component or start using `useReducer()` to expose an action which can be called from unrelated components if you need to set the value outside the component which holds the value itself.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti *Is this a React application?* I don't know. The website is not maintained by me. I'm just a user of the site and trying to write a userscript which is used only by me via greasemonkey. Thank you for your suggestion, anyway. I'll try to understand React (currently I'm not even a beginner of React).

Comment: If you need to automate a site you do not own you might want to try to send key events (keyDown & friends) instead of manipulating the HTML.

Comment: First random result (probably many better ones out there): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598909/how-to-simulate-a-keypress-in-a-greasemonkey-script